# haproxy load balancing per packet instead of per destination

Tags: haproxy

is there any way to configure HAproxy in order to balance the traffic between different backend servers?
So if the load balancer receives two messages one will go to Server1 and the other one to Server2 instade of both of them to the same server.

Thank you.

Comment: The haproxy docs are pretty clear about balance strategies - https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-balance. As I understand your question you are looking for roundrobin.

Comment: Additionally, the phrase "per packet" does not make sense here -- HAProxy is an HTTP and/or TCP proxy, both of which operate higher in the stack than "packets."  HTTP is layer 7 transactions, TCP is connection streams, neither of which is aware of packet boundaries.